# App loading issue after upgrading from Vaadin 23.1.0 to 23.2.8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

After upgrading to the latest release (23.2.8) from 23.1.0, I am able to successfully compile and deploy my application - however, it fails to load on the client side. I get an indefinitely flashing progress bar at the top of the page instead. Has anyone else run into this issue? I did not make any other changes to the code other than the version update in the POM.

Comment: Try removing `node_modules`, running `mvn clean` and then starting the app again. If things still don't work, please share some logs to help us figure out what's going on

Comment: What's in the dev-console of your browser? And the network tab there?